# Map dmo properties to smo - How

Tags: sql-server, smo

I have developed a utility to script all SQL Server objects using the deprecated DMO object. I intend to upgrade to SMO but not able to find the corresponding properties, for example, in DMO, we had
`Table.getKeys().Count`, `SQLDMO.Key, Table.getKeys()`

Can you please point me to some doc or tutorial as I found the Microsoft website not to be very useful.

I tried to replace DMO by SMO but as I said not able to find some mappings. Here is a piece of the original DMO code:

```
    If TB.getKeys().Count > 0 Then
        For Each k As SQLDMO.Key In TB.getKeys()
        KName = k.Name
        Select Case k.Type
        Case SQLDMO.SQLDMO_KEY_TYPE.SQLDMOKey_Primary, sqlMO.SQLDMO_KEY_TYPE.SQLDMOKey_Unique
        kExt = ".PKY"
        Case SQLDMO.SQLDMO_KEY_TYPE.SQLDMOKey_Foreign
        kExt = ".FKY"
        End Select
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such mapping! However you are able to slightly modify your code.

In order to enumerate foreign keys use the snippet as follows.

```
 ForeignKeyCollection fk = tbl.ForeignKeys;
  foreach (ForeignKey f in fk)
  {
     Console.WriteLine(f.Columns);
  }
```

Similar is with indexes. So, you can use the snippet as follows.

```
IndexCollection uk = tbl.Indexes;

            foreach (Index i in uk)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i.Name + ' ' + i.IsClustered + ' ' + i.IsUnique);
            }
```

### Updated - primary keys

For primary keys check out the snippet.

```
ColumnCollection cols = tbl.Columns;

            foreach (Column c in cols)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(c.InPrimaryKey);
            }
```

There is no great resources on the internet. 
But you can try this one

[Programming SQL Server with SQL Server Management Objects Framework](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/c-programming/programming-sql-server-sql-server-management-objects-framework/)

and this one

[Converting a Database to In-Memory OLTP](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/converting-database-memory-oltp/)

Comment: Thanks, how about primary keys?